# FontFamilly, FontSize, Color..settings in WPF app

Tags: wpf, settings

what is the best way for create settings (user can choose own font size, font family, color of text) in WPF app with MVVM design?

My ides is create setting class. An this class store/load from database when is wpf loading/closing.
Export this class with MEF and inject in view models classes and this properties of this setting class bind in view.

Something like this.

```
[Export(typeof IMySettings)]
public class MySetting : IMySettings
{
  //bind in view
  public FontFamily MyViewFont
  {
     get{return _myViewFont;}
     set
     {
        _myViewFont=value;
     }
  }
```

What do you think about it?
    }

Answer (score 0):

Settings class is fine. I myself call it a SettingsService but that doesn't matter. To save settings you can use the built-in support of .NET.

You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).
Good luck!